How to change background color of bottom sheet?
I cannot use a ZStack to fill the color because by content inside a bottom sheet is a searchable view. Hence the header is showing the color of the sheet. Is there a way to change the color using UIKit or SwiftUI (preferably)?
.sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isPresented) {
    ZStack {
        Color(.black)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        NavigationStack {
            SearchableView()
        }
    }
})

Update: -

Tried using .presentationBackground(.blue) and it changes the background of the content but the header is still the original color with the search bar



(How to make a sheet transparent) Use this to make it a different color.

Turns out it was the toolbarBackground that was showing, hiding it within the navigation stack and then using @Benzy Neez's solution of using presentationBackground(.black) sets the background of the entire sheet without using a ZStack.
.sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isPresented) {
            NavigationStack {
                AllEventsView(viewModel: viewModel, isMapView: true)
                    .toolbarBackground(.hidden)
            }
            .presentationBackground(.black)
}


Try using .presentationBackground:
.sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isPresented) {
    NavigationStack {
        SearchableView()
    }
    .presentationBackground(.black)
}



Tried using this - I've updated the outcome in the original post. I want to change the header color as well

@Rohan It works when I try it, so I am wondering how your SearchableView is implemented? Please update your post to provide a complete reproducible example.

Yep your answer solves part of the problem I've posted an answer check it out. Thanks for this!

struct MyContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            showSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
            Color(.black) // Set your desired background color
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                SearchableView()
            }
        })
        .modifier(CustomSheetBackground()) // Apply the custom modifier
    }
}

struct SearchableView: View {
    // Your searchable view content here
}

struct CustomSheetBackground: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea(.all)) // Set background color
    }
}

